# Implementing an external ADC in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, adc

I'm planning to use a ADS1220 4-channel 24 bit adc but I really have no experience with SPI. I have found [this](https://github.com/Protocentral/Protocentral_ADS1220/blob/master/Libraries/examples/Basic/Protocentral_ADS1220.ino) library but I can't really understand the code that much and also this is measuring the differential voltage. I want to use this for my accelerometer (x, y and z data) but I can't seem to find how to do read from 3 channels, and I can't understand the code in the library :( I've also found a video for this adc in youtube but he didn't used it for multiple channels. I'm sorry for asking this, I'm just pressured since the deadline is really soon.

### EDITED

---

### sketch

```
#include "Protocentral_ADS1220.h"
#include <SPI.h>

#define PGA 1                 // Programmable Gain = 1
#define VREF 3.3           
#define VFSR VREF/PGA             
#define FSR (((long int)1<<23)-1)  

volatile byte MSB;
volatile byte data;
volatile byte LSB;
//volatile char SPI_RX_Buff[3];
volatile byte *SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr;

long int bit32, data1, data2, data3;
long int bit24;

Protocentral_ADS1220 ADS1220;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ADS1220_CS_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ADS1220_DRDY_PIN, INPUT);

  ADS1220.begin();
  //ADS1220.Single_shot_mode_ON();
}

void loop() {

  byte *config_reg;

  data1 = aRead(0x81);
  data2 = aRead(0x91);
  data3 = aRead(0xA1);

  Serial.print(data1);
  Serial.print("    ");
  Serial.print(data2);
  Serial.print("    ");
  Serial.println(data3);
  delay(500);

}

long int aRead(uint8_t config_byte) {
  ADS1220.writeRegister(CONFIG_REG0_ADDRESS , config_byte);
  uint8_t r = ADS1220.readRegister(CONFIG_REG0_ADDRESS);
  //Serial.println(r,HEX);

  ADS1220.SPI_Start();

  while (ADS1220.NewDataAvailable == false) {
    SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr = ADS1220.Read_Data();
  }

  if(ADS1220.NewDataAvailable = true) {
    ADS1220.NewDataAvailable = false;

    MSB = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[0];    
    data = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[1];
    LSB = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[2];

    bit24 = MSB;
    bit24 = (bit24 << 8) | data;
    bit24 = (bit24 << 8) | LSB;        

    bit24= ( bit24 << 8 );
    bit32 = ( bit24 >> 8 );
  }

  return bit32;
}
```

I tried to use the above sketch and I successfully read from 3 different channels but I noticed that the readings vary too much, compared to the example code. In the example code when I turn my potentiometer full CW, it outputs 8388607 which is correct right? since it is signed int.

But when running this sketch, the image below shows the output when the potentiometer is fully CW. Also turning the potentiometer fully CCW leads to negative values (shown in the 2nd picture) but in the example code, it gives 100-300 decimal values.  Also these are the configuration registers I sent in registers 1-3 (I edited it in the part of the [library](https://github.com/Protocentral/Protocentral_ADS1220/blob/master/Libraries/Protocentral_ADS1220.cpp)) and for register 0, it is on the sketch.

`Config_Reg1 = 0x00;
 Config_Reg2 = 0x40;
 Config_Reg3 = 0x00;`

[image: serial monitor output]
 [image]

#### using accelerometer

format is (x,y,z)
[image]

Comment: What kind of deadline? School project or assignment?

Comment: Writing ADC driver code from scratch is NOT easy.  What is wrong with the ADC built into most Arduino's processors?  The ADC driver for most Arduino's is already part of the Arduino SDK.

Comment: What's the model number of the accelerometer? Many of them digitize their results already.

Comment: @MikaelPatel it's for my thesis in college

Comment: @jwpat7 adxl335, this has analog outputs, my adviser wants to have a 24 bit output accelerometer, I know there are lots of accelerometer that has 16 bit output which is already enough for precise measurements but I wanna give a try implementing an external adc before suggesting to my adviser to use accelerometers with digitized outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an understanding of how to read from the various ADS1220 channels, first review Figure 38, Analog Input Multiplexer, in the Datasheet as obtained from a link on [TI.com's ADS1220 technicaldocuments webpage](http://www.ti.com/product/ADS1220/technicaldocuments).

[image: Figure 38]
As can be seen, you'll need to close a switch from an AINx input line to the AINₚ bus, and also close the switch between AINₙ and AVSS.  The IDACx switches and the BCS switches should remain open.

To operate those switches, first look at §8.6.1, Configuration Registers, in the Register Map section of the Datasheet.  You'll see that MUX bits are in register 0, BCS is in register 1, IDAC is in register 2, and IxMUX are in register 3.  To see what to put into those fields, look at Tables 16, 17, 19, and 20.  For the MUX field, you will want a binary value like 1000, 1001, 1010, or 1011 to select one of AIN0-AIN3 as the AINₚ input and AVSS as the AINₙ input.  BCS, IDAC, I1MUX, and I2MUX all should be zero.

For example, to read channels 0, 1, 2 in sequence, set MUX to 1000, set up other register fields, and trigger a conversion.  After reading the result, change MUX to 1001, trigger a conversion, read result,  change MUX to 1010, trigger a conversion, read result, etc.

---

*Edit 1:* In slightly more detail, one could do as follows.

> • Use a WREG command [as in §8.5.3.6; or some library equivalent] to send three bytes to set up Configuration Registers 1, 2, 3.
>   • For i=0, 1, and 2 in turn, construct a configuration byte, send that byte to Configuration Register 0, start a conversion, await result, read result; as follows:
>
> > Set the MUX field of a byte to i
> >     Set PGA as desired (ie, to 1, 2, or 4, via codes 000, 001, or 010)
> >     Set the PGA_BYPASS bit (as required when AINₙ = AVSS)
> >     Use a WREG to send the constructed byte to Configuration Register 0
> >     Use a START/SYNC command to start a conversion (see §8.5.3.2)
> >     Wait for DRDY to go low
> >     Use an RDATA command to read iᵗʰ ADC result (see §8.5.3.4)

---

*Edit 2:* In [Protocentral's ADS1220.ino sketch](https://github.com/Protocentral/Protocentral_ADS1220/blob/master/Libraries/examples/Basic/Protocentral_ADS1220.ino), one finds the code sequence

```
  MSB = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[0];    
  data = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[1];
  LSB = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[2];
  bit24 = MSB;
  bit24 = (bit24 << 8) | data;
  bit24 = (bit24 << 8) | LSB; // Converting 3 bytes to a 24 bit int
  bit24= ( bit24 << 8 );
  bit32 = ( bit24 >> 8 );     // Converting 24 bit two's complement to 32 bit two's complement
```

More competently and concisely, and with `SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr` renamed to `SPI_RX_Buff`, this could be written as:

```
  bit32 = (((long)(SPI_RX_Buff[0]<<8 | SPI_RX_Buff[1])<<8 | SPI_RX_Buff[2])<<8)>>8;
```

which acts as follows:  Assemble three bytes from `SPI_RX_Buff` into a 24-bit twos-complement-signed number.  Shift that number left 8 bits so that its sign bit now sits in the sign bit position of a 32-bit signed integer.  Shift that result 8 bits right with sign extension so that the final result is a signed 32-bit integer with possible values from -2²³ up to (2²³-1).

Sign extension occurs – usually – because in [many implementations of C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c), the `>>` operator does an [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) instead of a [logical shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) when its operand is signed.

Comment: I just read this and it made me understand the datasheet, thank you so much!! I'll just update you if I was able to make it work

Comment: hello I'm wondering what would I send first when I want to read the data. I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiUp7xVxbkc) youtube video and he started with setting CS to low (which I think I should also do in my case) then sends a byte which is equal primary byte with a start bit and single/diff mode `and` to a register mask that isolates 3 LSB. I'm sorry if I'm noob but it would mean a lot to me if you help

Comment: I'm guessing I should send all those 4 configuration registers? I just don't know the flow I'm sorry

Comment: oh I get it why he `and` it with a mask, just to be sure that the config register will not be changed during the process, now my main concern is how to send these configuration registers

Comment: Edit 1 reflects my understanding (from datasheet) of the process - I haven't tried it out, and haven't looked at what library calls might apply

Comment: thank you so much for the fast reply, I'll figure this one tomorrow since its 4 am already but I did a quick scan and now I can at least understand the library already, really appreciate your help! I hope I can do more than saying thanks because your did really help me a lot with the information you gave!

Comment: hello I just continued following what you wrote and looking for the commands written in the library, also in your edited line did you mean for the gain in this line _Set PGA as desired (ie, to 1, 2, or 4, via codes 000, 001, or 010)_ ? as I've read in the datasheet the commands corresponds to the gain. I was also a bit confused in the [library](https://github.com/Protocentral/Protocentral_ADS1220/blob/master/Libraries/Protocentral_ADS1220.cpp) on the reading of data part.

Comment: It is written on line `235`, why did he used a loop in reading the data and in the [example](https://github.com/Protocentral/Protocentral_ADS1220/blob/master/Libraries/examples/Basic/Protocentral_ADS1220.ino) extracted the data buffer in line `58` do I also need to read the value like this? and also he sent `SPI_MASTER_DUMMY` which is equal to 0xFF. In the datasheet RDATA command is like this `0001 xxxx`, does this mean that the **x**'s are considered 0? so when I read for data I should send a command byte of `0001 0000` and loop it again for the other channels right?

Comment: Only gains of 1,2,4 are available for single-ended input, and their codes are 000, 001, 010 in the gain field, which is above the PGA_BYPASS bit in the config byte.  The `for` loop at line 243 in Protocentral_ADS1220.cpp loops 3 times to read all 3 data bytes of result.  As noted in [SPITransfer](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer) at arduino.cc,  “SPI transfer is based on a simultaneous send and receive”; if sent data is irrelevant, dummy it.  In `0001 xxxx` each x is a don't-care, so can be anything. §8.5.4 says  “An RDATA command does not have to be sent”  after DRDY goes low.

Comment: okay thanks again for the help, so I would stick to the library with the for loop in reading right? I'm still a bit confused with the dummy thing, what does it mean if send data is irrelevant? but basically I'll get my reading with the code inside this function right? `uint8_t * Protocentral_ADS1220::Read_Data()` since it checked for the DRDY to go low so no need for RDATA command

Comment: I also have a question in the pin configuration, does AVSS go to ground?

Comment: You may need to experiment some with that library.  It uses some 100 μs delays (before dropping CS) that appear unnecessary  and it may improperly depend on delays instead of busy-waiting on flags.  It also uses an if statement instead of a while to check if DRDY *is* low, rather than busy-waiting for DRDY to *go* low.  ¶  AVSS is analog low-side voltage (see Pin Functions table, page 4 of specs), typically ground, but some people like to  keep it separate from digital ground DGND.  ¶  Do some web searching for "Analog ground", "busy wait", etc.

Comment: hello I tried the library already and it's working, I also added an external reference successfully. I just wanna clarify what you wrote at the top, in my case I should always write a configuration byte to Register 0 right? does this also mean I should change my conversion mode into single-shot? so that every time I write the config byte then I'll start a conversion with the START/SYNC command? the wait for DRDY to go low and read the data, then another configuration byte to the next channel and so on..

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of what you need to do.

Comment: hello sorry to bother you again but if you don't mind, please take a look at the edited part. thank you so much!

Comment: I'll look at it more later this week - no time ATM - after setting up on a channel try several readings in a row before going to next channel to see if readings settle in

Comment: no luck, i tried reading only one channel in single shot mode, still same result. it maxes out at 83875xx and -9xxx as minimum reading

Comment: Though I  think depending on my application, i don't really reach the minimum and maximum values since I have -/+3g accelerometer for measuring vibration and it's unlikely for it to reach more than -/+1g. I am having doubt though on the values I'm getting using the accelerometer, I added it at the top. The values should reflect 0g on x and y axis and 1g on z axis. For example I am only getting the +8388608, the value for 0g should be expected to be half of it (between 0-+8388608 = 4194304) but it seems like it's far than that. Also ow can I get the whole `2^24 = 16777216` analog levels?

Comment: I asked how to get the whole 2^24 levels since I don't really understand the code above for `bit24` and `bit32` variables

Comment: i actually tried to convert these values to g values and it pretty much does the job!! i got precise measurements now really thanks a lot to your help!!!! and Merry Christmas by the way!

Comment: See edit 2 regarding  code with variables bit24 and bit32.   ¶ If the library code turns out to be too slow, there are a dozen or two unnecessary delay(2)'s and delay(5)'s and delayMicroseconds(100)'s egregiously scattered around in Protocentral_ADS1220.cpp.  You probably can remove most of those, or change all the 2's and 5's to 1's, etc